# Overwrite checkout cart for simple type products

Tags: php, magento

i have created custom module in module's config.xml I am calling check.xml

```
   <config>
    <frontend>
            <routers>
                <test>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Check_Test</module>
                        <frontName>test</frontName>
                    </args>
                </test>
            </routers>
        <layout>
                <updates>
                    <test>
                        <file>check.xml</file>
                    </test>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>



    </config>
```

In my check.xml i am overwriting  checkout cart.

```
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
       <action method="addItemRender">
          <type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>dd
/default.phtml</template>
       </action>
    </reference>
```

In my default.phtml i am using die.
but it is not working it is still displaying default checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missed the layout tag in the check.xml. Please add the

```
<layout version="0.1.0"> Your Code Here </layout>
```

i.e.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
       <action method="addItemRender">
          <type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>dd
/default.phtml</template>
       </action>
    </reference>
</layout>
```

It may solve your problem.

Thanks